# Dockerコンテナの時間をHostの時間と合わせる

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, docker

Docker for Macを使ってUbuntu 16.10を実行しているのですが、ゲスト側の時間とホスト側の時間が一致しません
どうすれば合わせられるのでしょうか?

macOSの時間

```
$ date
2017年 3月14日 火曜日 22時30分27秒 JST
```

Ubuntuの時間

```
$ date
2017年  3月 14日 火曜日 12:50:06 UTC
```

まず、macOSで`date`を実行し、その2~3秒後にubuntuで実行しました
そのため数秒のズレはあると思いますが、これほど大きくはならないと思います

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[本家ドキュメントのKnown issues](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/troubleshoot/#known-issues) に載っている問題です。
NTPサーバに接続できない場合、休止状態から戻った時に時刻が同期されないとのことです。

解決策として2つ挙げられていて、
1. 休止状態から復帰した時に `docker run --rm --privileged alpine hwclock -s` を実行して手動で同期させる
2. 低優先度のNTPサーバとしてlocalclockを参照させる

一時的に使用する分には1.の方法で十分かもですが、常時Dockerを動作させる場合は2.の方がいいかと思います。